# sharing a PyTable across multiprocesses

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6, pytables

I create a PyTable object `W_hat` where processes should share  and save the results their instead of returning them.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tables as tb


def parallel_l21(labels, X, lam, g, W_hat):
    g_indxs = np.where(labels == g)[0]
    tmp = rfs(X[g_indxs, 1:].T, X[:, :-1].T, gamma=lam, verbose=False).T
    tmp[abs(tmp) <= 1e-6] = 0
    with lock:
        W_hat[:, g_indxs] = np.array(tmp)


def init_child(lock_):
    global lock
    lock = lock_

#Previous code is omitted. 
n_ = X_test.shape[0]
tb.file._open_files.close_all()
f = tb.open_file(path_name + 'dot' + sub_num + str(lam) + '.h5', 'w')
filters = tb.Filters(complevel=5, complib='blosc')
W_hat = f.create_carray(f.root, 'data', tb.Float32Atom(), shape=(n_, n_), filters=filters)
W_hats = []
for i in np.unique(labels):
     W_hats.append(W_hat)
lock = Lock()
with Pool(processes=cpu_count, initializer=init_child, initargs=(lock,)) as pool:
     print(pool)
     pool.starmap(parallel_l21, zip(repeat(labels), repeat(X), repeat(lam), np.unique(labels), W_hats))
```

Now, when running into `starmap`, this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE 2.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in tables.hdf5extension.Array.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: self.dims,self.dims_chunk,self.maxdims cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling
```

---

Note: I thought that the code works fine on Python `3.6.8` but it turns out that it is not the case.

Comment: The code you're showing has very little to do with the error.  The traceback shows that it's trying to pickle an hdf5 object.  Is `tables.hdf5extension` one of your modules?

Comment: Python 3.8 changed the default pickling protocol from 3 to 4; not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Are you using the same version of PyTable for each Python version?

Comment: @TimRoberts the idea of `tables` is to save the variable on hard disk using `hdf5`.

Comment: @WillDaSilva Yes, it is `3.6.1`

Comment: @rando I think you should try to find what the minimal reproducible case is for this issue, and then raise it with the PyTables issue tracker: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues

Comment: Adding to comment above, verify your code works _**before**_ adding the `multiprocessing` package. I think the error is in your PyTables code. You create `W_hat` as an empty CArray of `shape=(n_, n_)`. Then you loop thru `labels`, appending an empty list `W_hats`  to the CArray. _**However**_, CArray does not have an `.append()` method -- you need to use slice notation to write to the appropriate indices for `W_hats`, **OR** create it as an EArray to use append. Also, why are you appending an empty list?

Comment: @kcw78 it is a workaround for `starmap`. I just pass the same object 'W_hat' to `parallel_l21 ` function. `W_hats` is a list contains pointers to `W_hat`. 2. I verified the code without multiprocessing and it works fine. Anyway, I think sharing a PyTable between processes is not trivial. The authors recommanded doing multiple queues to make it work. See: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/master/examples/multiprocess_access_queues.py

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Sorry! I got cross-eyed reading `W_hats` and `W_hat`. There is a 2nd PyTables example here: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/master/examples/multiprocess_access_benchmarks.py It shows 3 different methods: 1) multiprocessing.Pipe, 2) a shared memory mapped file and 3) using sockets: either an IPv4 socket, or Unix domain socket (on Linux only). `h5py` is an alternative to work with HDF5 that uses the `mpi4py` package. Finally, you might be interested in the `multitables` package described here: https://github.com/ghcollin/multitables